# Unable to customize color settings for Code Coverage Result in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, nunit, code-coverage

I wanted to customize color settings for Code Coverage Result in Visual Studio, but when I tried doing this with a solution suggested somewhere as shown below:

> > > To change color, or customize the style, you need to open Options
> > >       Dialog window, from Tools –> Options.  Then search for “Fonts and
> > >       Colors” option in the right side tree explorer.  Once Fonts and Colors
> > >       is selected, search for “Coverage… “ under Display Items. You will
> > >       find following three Display items  ◾Coverage Not Touched Area ◾Coverage Partially Touched Area  ◾Coverage Touched Area

But I am unable to see the following options in the list:

1. Coverage Not Touched Area
2. Coverage Partially Touched Area
3. Coverage Touched Area

Can anyone suggest me how to add these options in that list?

Comment: Can anyone answer this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Close VS.
2. Then try running **devenv /resetuserdata** in visual studio command prompt.
3. Re open VS and see if these options are found.
4. Otherwise you just have to repair your VS. That should enable these options.